# How do I export my pem file to pfx with a password on the command line

Tags: bash, openssl, password, convert

I need to pass the password via the command line during the exporting in a bash script.

IBM has this on their website

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "$pem" -inkey "$key" -out "$pfx" -passout pass:pkcs12 "$pfxpass";
```

The above does not work for me.

The command below works but then you are prompted to enter and reenter a password.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "$pem" -inkey "$key" -out "$pfx";
```

How can this be scripted?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Do you get an error message? What OS and OpenSSL version is this?

Comment: `root@pl /home/remove # openssl pkcs12 -export -in me.pem -inkey me.key -out me.pfx -passout pass:pkcs12 uberpassword    
Usage: pkcs12 [options]  
where options are  
-export       output PKCS12 file  
-chain        add certificate chain  
-inkey file   private key if not infile  
-certfile f   add all certs in f  
-CApath arg   - PEM format directory of CA's  
-CAfile arg   - PEM format file of CA's  
-name "name"  use name as friendly name  
`  

OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I don't understand this part: `-passout pass:pkcs12 "$pfxpass"`. `-passout pass:pkcs12` will use `pkcs12` as the password, the rest will be treated as another parameter and probably cause the command to fail. I personally recommend not using `pass:...` and set the password into an environment variable and then `-passout env:varname`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `-passin` in your command, due to the key you've used in the `-inkey` needs a password. Also, the exported pkcs12 file will need a password, so you need to use `-passout` as well.
So, assuming you'll use the same password for the imported an exported keys, you should use this command.

```
openssl pkcs12 \
  -export \
  -in "$pem" -inkey "$key" -passin pass:"$pfxpass" \
  -passout pass:"$pfxpass" -out "$pfx"
```

Hope it helps!